# My Ubuntu server keeps "turning off" after some time

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, security, firewall, node.js

I'm new to server administration and whatever I know comes from my amateurish knowledge of linux and guides I followed online to setup an ubuntu 16.04 server for a production node app being served via a reverse proxy setup by nginx.

In short I followed the following guides, in order:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://github.com/imthenachoman/How-To-Secure-A-Linux-Server

Now, the problem is it seems my server runs fine for some time and then after a few days I try loading the website and it says the server is refusing the connection.

I have no idea why that's happening; I check the server status on my admin control panel for the server and it says everything is fine, when I try to open a connection to the server via the ssh client that *they* provide I can login fine and run commands just fine, but when I try to ssh into the server via my local terminal it tells me the remote host identification has changed.

There seems to be no "real" problem as when I request a server restart everything returns to normal.

Finally, I should mention that we haven't yet linked our server IP to the domain name we purchased as we're still testing a few features. But using the IP to navigate to the website works just fine.

I'm really grateful for any help or guidance on this. Thank you for your time.

---

#### **EDIT (Additional information as requested):**

For my ssh client I'm not using the domain name, just the IP. But the main problem is when opening the website in the browser with the IP I get "connection refused" as an error

I'm not sure if there was a proxy installed by my VPS provider. I am using a basic unmanaged VPS solution by a2hosting.

When I run `systemctl status nginx`, the command reports no errors and shows the service as active.

Comment: There a few things we need for clarification: 1. Are you using a DNS name in your ssh client?
2. Are the servers behind the proxy setup on a cloud provider?
3. Are there any errors being reported by Nginx proxy? Basically more information would be beneficial.

Comment: I think you should ask your server provider's support this question.

Comment: @Tim I would consider asking support but I just want to make sure that there's nothing wrong that I'm doing in terms of setup. Also, they're not very happy to provide support as I opted for the most basic unmanaged package that they offer.

Comment: @DavidO. I've updated my post to reflect the additional information.

Comment: After this happens you need to log in via the working SSH and see what the problem is. I'd look at syslog to see if there's anything in there, see if iptables has been turned on. It's a bit of an odd one, you'll probably have to poke around a bit. If you can't solve it you may need to pay support to help you.

Comment: @Tim My server's down now, should I provide the output to `dmesg -H | tail`? I have no idea what I'm looking at. At this point I'm also open to suggestions for other server providers...

Comment: I'm not a Linux admin, I know bits and pieces, so I don't really know how to diagnose this. I'd look at the syslog to see if there's anything interesting. I'd look at the web server logs. I'd check if services are still running (nginx / apache / sshd). Before you look for a new provider it might be worth contacting support, telling them you're frustrated and considering leaving, and ask if they can help. Hard to say if it's the provider or something you've done in the OS.